# Rails - Make two different footers to appear on certain pages

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to have two different footers, and have one appear on specific pages.  The site has a lot of pages, so I don't want to just hardcode each footer into each page.

In rails, how can I put in logic to have which footer appears on which page?  Is there an 'if' statement I can put directly on the _footer partial that displays the footer by page?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to have two different layouts. If you show me some of your code i will be about to help you out a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You can crate two different layouts( add **.erb** file to direcroty **layouts** in views ) or can create two partial and use them when you want, for example:

In your Controller add

```
class Controller
...
# You may use class or instrance variable
def your_method
  # your logic...
  @footer_variable = true
end
```

in your layout file add

```
<%= if @footer_variable %>
  <%= render 'optional_footer' %>
<%= else %>
  <%= render 'footer' %>
<%= end %>
```

and add to your layout's directory file **footer.html.erb** with your normal footer and **optional_footer.html.erb**

**Optional Footer**

```
<div>
  <span>I'm your optional footer</span>
</div>
```

**Normal Footer**

```
<div>
  <span>I'm your normal footer</span>
</div>``
```

If instance variable will be availiable in layout it will ber rendered optional footer otherwise normal footer( from your layout )